# Field initialization in java class outside the methods' bodies

Tags: java, initialization

Please explain below behavior, why first statement is valid while other one is invalid and throws error.

```
public class Test{
    private String firstName="John";// is Valid
    //Below is invalid
    private String lastName; 
    lastname="Doe";
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A class can only contain *declarations* (and static/instance initializers). A field declaration can contain an initializer, as per `firstName` - and your declaration of `lastName` is valid, but the assignment after it is just a *statement*, and a class can't directly contain statements.

If you want to separate declaration from assignment, you either need to put the assignment in a constructor:

```
public class Test {
    private String lastName;

    public Test() {
        lastName = "Doe";
    }
}
```

or use an [instance initializer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.6) (less common in my experience):

```
public class Test {
    private String lastName;

    {
        lastName = "Doe";
    }
}
```